# Eclipse 3.7.2 won't create android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having trouble creating a project for android.  I have upgraded the SDK to Jelly Bean, and eclipse, but now I see a new create project template, that stops at Install Dependancies.  I want the Android Support Library Version 8, but I have version 9 installed.  If anyone know how to proceed, please advise.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 4):

Something broken, having the same issue here. Uninstalled Android Support Library from Android SDK Manager then when creating a new project and prompted to install the library, click install, these steps seem to work.

Comment: @Yongki, I have the same problem, can you explain me how to uninstall the Android Support Library from the Android SDK please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yongki I got it done, thanks, if I could accept your answer I would have done it!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but for me the uninstall/reinstall library method doesn't work. 
However I found a way to make a new project:

- Find a HelloWorld project ( Maybe you have one already, else ask from someone to send it to you or download it from internet )
- Import it to Eclipse.
- Use it as a template and simply Copy/Paste it to create a new project.

It's not the BEST solution, but since I can't find another one this will do for now, until they fix the problem.